# n variable polynomial + /-if the number of $-1$'s is even, or odd, respectively. Prove that the degree of this polynomial is at least $n$.

Tags: polynomials

Consider a polynomial in $n$ variables with real coefficients. We know that if every variable is $\pm1$, the value of the polynomial is positive, or negative if the number of $-1$'s is even, or odd, respectively. Prove that the degree of this polynomial is at least $n$.

n variables make the polynomial more interesting

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Comment: I got this problem from AoPs

Comment: URL, please, so we can all join in the fun?

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/u257453h1213005p6022786

Comment: Too bad the person who put it on AoPS didn't give any information about it.